# HTML form with multiple image-select via Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm building an HTML form that will have the user select an image, a url and a text that will be added as a `<li>` into a web page. My problem is that I want the user to be able to create more than one `<li>` per input and I thought the easiest way to do this is by assigning the values into arrays, butthis generates the following problems for me...

the image is selected via a button that opens a file-browser window (elfinder to be exact), which is manipulated through a javascript and I have no idea how to make it add the image on each different `<li>`. 
Here is the javascript:

```
<div class="picture">
    <span>No picture?Use the browse button to select one!</span>
</div>
<input type="text" class="featured_image" placeholder="Featured Image" name="featured_image[]" hidden="true">
<input type="button" value="Browse" class="imageUpload" ></li>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.imageUpload').popupWindow({ 
        windowURL:'elfinder/alone_elfinder.html?mode=image', 
        windowName:'Filebrowser',
        height:490, 
        width:950,
        centerScreen:1
    }); 
    function processFile(file) {
        $('.picture').html('<img src="' + file + '" />');
        $('.featured_image').val(file);
    }
</script>
```

I have tried to search the web, but that's how far I've got with a working code. At least I believe I have the php figured out, so the question is mostly on how to make the arrays work in the javascript.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I changed the form it looks like this:

```
<div class="slide" id="slide1">
    <input type="button" value="Browse" class="imageUpload">
    <div class="picture">
                <span>No picture?Use the browse button to select one!</span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="featured_image" placeholder="Featured Image" name="featured_image[]">
</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide2">
    <input type="button" value="Browse" class="imageUpload" >
    <div class="picture">
                <span>No picture?Use the browse button to select one!</span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="featured_image" placeholder="Featured Image" name="featured_image[]">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.imageUpload').popupWindow({ 
            windowURL:'elfinder/alone_elfinder.html?mode=image', 
            windowName:'Filebrowser',
            height:490, 
            width:950,
            centerScreen:1
    }); 
    function processFile(file){
        $(this).parent("div").children(".picture").html('<img src="' + file + '" />');
    }
</script>
```

But ofc it doesn't work because the `$(this).parent("div").children(".picture")` targets the file instead of the button.
Can I have it somehow target the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue with adding a simple `.click` function that marks the corresponding div, now the Javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.imageUpload').click(function() {
    $(".active-slide").removeClass("active-slide");
            $(this).parent("div").addClass("active-slide")
    });
    $('.imageUpload').popupWindow({ 
            windowURL:'elfinder/alone_elfinder.html?mode=image', 
            windowName:'Filebrowser',
            height:490, 
            width:950,
            centerScreen:1
    }); 
    function processFile(file){
        $(".active-slide").children(".picture").html('<img src="' + file + '" />');
        $(".active-slide").children(".featured_image").val(file);
        $(".active-slide").removeClass("active-slide");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was very helpful, I ended up doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(function() {  
    $('.imageUpload').click(function() {
        $(".active-slide").removeClass("active-slide");
        $(this).parent("p").addClass("active-slide")
    });


    $('.imageUpload').popupWindow({ 
        windowURL:'/elfinder/elfinder_popup.php', 
        windowName:'Filebrowser',
        height:490, 
        width:950,
        centerScreen:1
    });
});  
function processFile(file){
    $(".active-slide").children(".picture").html('<img src="' + file + '" />');
    $(".active-slide").children(".xFilePath").val(file);
    $(".active-slide").removeClass("active-slide");
```

}

```
<p>
<span class="picture"></span><br />
Image 1 <input type="text" class="xFilePath" id="xFilePath1" name="FilePath1" size="70"/><input type="button" value="Browse Server" class="imageUpload"/><br />
Image 1 Caption Overlay: <input type="text" id="xFileText1" name="FileText1" size="100"/> </p>



<p>
 <span class="picture"></span><br />
Image 2 <input type="text" class="xFilePath" id="xFilePath2" name="FilePath2" size="70"/><input type="button" value="Browse Server" class="imageUpload"/><br />
Image 2 Caption Overlay: <input type="text" id="xFileText2" name="FileText2" size="100"/> </p>



<p>
 <span class="picture"></span><br />
Image 3 <input type="text" class="xFilePath" id="xFilePath3" name="FilePath3" size="70"/><input type="button" value="Browse Server" class="imageUpload" /><br />
Image 3 Caption Overlay: <input type="text" id="xFileText3" name="FileText3" size="100"/> </p>

<p>
 <span class="picture"></span><br />
Image 4 <input type="text" class="xFilePath" id="xFilePath4" name="FilePath4" size="70"/><input type="button" value="Browse Server" class="imageUpload" /><br />
Image 4 Caption Overlay: <input type="text" id="xFileText4" name="FileText4" size="100"/> </p>

<p>
 <span class="picture"></span><br />
Image 5 <input type="text" class="xFilePath" id="xFilePath5" name="FilePath5" size="70"/><input type="button" value="Browse Server" class="imageUpload" /><br />
Image 5 Caption Overlay: <input type="text" id="xFileText5" name="FileText5" size="100"/> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to submit your form, then do something like this.
First remove the `.featured_image` image input, we can create it dynamically, 
and your function `processFile` will be..

```
function processFile( file ) {
  $('.picture span').remove();
  $('<img />').attr("src",file).appendTo( $('.picture') );
  $("<input />",{
    "type": "hidden",
    "class": "featured_image",
    "placeholder": "Featured Image",
    "name": "featured_image[]",
    "value": file
  }).insertAfter( $(".picture") );
}
```

Comment: While it does allow to add more than one image, it adds the images on all `.picture`. I want to have different "add image" buttons for each image, so that they can be changed.